# How do you check if bncert-tool is already setup and running on Amazon Lightsail Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

We are using the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool from the read me below.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/understand-bncert/

Is there a way to check if bncert has already been setup? Not just installed but is currently running SSL certificates created with that tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you ran the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool, you can easily verify if everything is configured properly:

- Access your website using https://yourdomain.com. Does it have a valid certificate (green padlock next to the domain you just wrote)?
- Check the Apache's configuration: This command should return the certificates Apache is currently using:

```
cat /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf | grep SSLCertificate
```

Are they your domain's certificates?

- Check that the renewal process is configured: There should be an entry in crontab to renew the certificate during the next months. Run this command to verify it

```
sudo crontab -l -u bitnami
```

Is everything correct? So your site is safe :)

Comment: World's longest delayed response, but this did help and we've been running smooth the Let's Encrypt certs for some time now. Wanted to say thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be

```
cat /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf | grep SSLCertificate
```

as the other file does not have the SSLCertificate in it.